# how to run sidekiq in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am new in rails. just want to know who i can run `sidekiq` in product mode as a service. I am not using `capistano` or any deployment tool. I have a thought like creating a initializer file like `sidekiq.rb` and inside that put a line like `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq`. Please let me know the best solution.

Comment: use capistrano... just do it, and thank me later =)

Answer (score 3):

Learn your OS's service manager.  In Ubuntu, this is Upstart.  You need to create the scripts so your OS knows to start Sidekiq on bootup.  There are examples for Upstart and Runit here:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples

Capistrano will not start Sidekiq on bootup.

Answer (score 1):

You can create init script for Sidekiq and use that to start or stop it.

I had referred once below link for the same

https://cdyer.co.uk/blog/init-script-for-sidekiq-with-rbenv/

Answer (score 0):

Try

`bundle exec sidekiq --environment production`

Looking at the help for sidekiq, this should be the command you are looking for:

```
sidekiq --help

-c, --concurrency INT            processor threads to use
-d, --daemon                     Daemonize process
-e, --environment ENV            Application environment
```

Comment: yes but how i can use it as a service ?? so that every time i need not have to write the same

Answer (score 0):

You can start it by running `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_config.yml -d -L /path/to/logs/folder/log/sidekiq.log`

***sidekiq_config example:***

```
# sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_config.yml
---
:environment: production
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:concurrency:  4
:queues:
  - default
  - ts_delta
```

To stop it you can run `ps ax | grep sidekiq` get the process number and kill it like running `kill <process number>`.